# Codename One - Improve Layout Animation Usage

Tags: animation, codenameone, codebase

Following the instructions in this [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/animations.html) about Animations and Transitions, it is noted that animation done on the `Form` level requires taking the contentpane as the actual `Container`. So instead of

```
form.animateLayout(1000);
```

one has to do

```
form.getContentPane().animateLayout(1000);
```

While the documentation points out this exception, wouldnt it be easier and more user-friendly to update the `animateLayout()` function to check whether the intended Component to do the animation for is a Form itself and if so, automatically getting its content pane?

This would remove this exception handling from the user side and make it more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that makes sense. There are a lot of methods that constantly get added/changed and we still didn't add everything that needs adding. In this commit I added a few: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/4b848039ec6619bf3d6dae3cfe6b8b8d9a7ff115